# Javascript variable comparison

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements, console.log

Can anyone give me some thoughts as to why number1 is being logged as 0 even though it should be logged as 1(or at least I think so)? I'm new to Javascript.

```
var array = [3,1,2];
var array2 = []
var number1 = 0; 
var number2 = 0;
var number3 = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if(array[i] > number3) {
   number3 = array[i]

  }
  else if(array[i] > number2) {
    number2 = array[i];
  }
  else if (array[i] > number1) {
     number1 = array[i];
  }
}
console.log(number1)
console.log(number2)
console.log(number3)
```

Comment: Pretty simple - CTRL-F for `number1 = `. It's only assigned once - as 0. Seems like a basic mistake - I think you have the third else the wrong way around.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you reassign or increment `number1`.

Comment: number1 is assigned 0, and that's it. It's never assigned to again.

Comment: In programming, `a = x` is `a <- x` in pseudo-code. It's not a commutative operation as it is in Mathematics. So, `number1` has its default value because you don't change it.

Comment: Use debug tools and start getting used to it, is my advice to you

Answer (score 4):

In this code, the only assignment to `number1` is the line that declares it, which assigns the value 0. Did you perhaps mean for this line:

```
array[i] = number1;
```

...to read:

```
number1 = array[i];
```

?

Comment: See the comment by @TyAnthoney -- you only have 3 numbers in the array, and the way the loop is structured, it will write both the second and third numbers to `number2`.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and guess that you're looking to identify the largest 3 numbers in the array. Ignore this if that isn't the case, but by far the simplest and most intuitive way to do this is going to be to sort the entire array and then take the last 3 values: `array.sort(); var largest3 = array.slice(-3);`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the logic of your statements and the fact that you are performing the incorrect assignment. This is what is happening

First iteration: 
3 > 0 so number3 = 3
Second iteration: 
1 !> 3 so we move to the second conditional where 1 > 0 so number2 = 1
third iteration: 
2 !> 3 and 2 > 1 so number2 = 2 then the loop is done

Once you fix the boolean login assigning array[index] to number1 will work

Answer (score 1):

I SEE YOU FIXED THE "array[i] = number1;" to be the right way.  If still having trouble understanding issues i sometimes put in crude debugging using "alerts"  -  see bottom of my post .

Looks to me like you simply set it to 0  in line 3 (var number1 = 0; ) 
and never set it to anything else.

lets go loop by loop.

loop 1:

```
if(array[i] > number3) {
 number3 = array[i]
}
```

number3 = 0 on first loop and array[0] = 3, so value of array[0] will be assigned to number3, making number3 = 3

loop 2:
will now skip to this  else if

```
else if(array[i] > number2) {
 number2 = array[i];
}
```

number2 = 0 on second loop and array[1] = 1, so value of array[1] will be assigned to number2, making number2 = 1

loop 3:
will also hit the first else if since number2 = 1 and array[i] = 2
now number2 will be assigned 2

```
else if(array[i] > number2) {
 number2 = array[i];
}
```

now your looping is done then with out hitting 
the last else if.  so number1 still equals 0
besides that you are doing
array[i] = number1;
when you should do something like 
number1 = array[i] instead

```
else if (array[i] > number1) {
 array[i] = number1;
}
```

at least this is what it looks like it's doing to me.

Sample alerts to help debug.

```
<script>
var array = [3,1,2];
var array2 = []
var number1 = 0; 
var number2 = 0;
var number3 = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

alert( 'array['+i+']='+array[i] + ', number3 ='+number3 + ',  number2 ='+number2 + ',  number1 ='+number1) 

  if(array[i] > number3) {
   number3 = array[i];
   alert (' got here A');

  }
  else if(array[i] > number2) {
    number2 = array[i];
    alert (' got here B');
  }
  else if (array[i] > number1) {
     number1 = array[i];
     alert (' got here C');
  }
}
console.log(number1)
console.log(number2)
console.log(number3)
</script>
```

hope that helps.

Comment: In summary, the data in he array dictates that `number2` is set twice: `1` is greater than `0` sets `number2`, and `2` is greater than `1` sets `number2` as well. `number1` never gets looked at or set.

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to be looking for the three highest, positive, different values in an an array of numbers. If so it suffers a logic flaw that the value overwritten in an existing highest value could be a candidate for the next highest value but does not get checked. Code that produces the kind of result  apparently expected needs to perform such a check, *as for example*:

```
var array = [3,1,2];
var array2 = []
var number1 = 0; 
var number2 = 0;
var number3 = 0;
var number, temp;

for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  number = array[i];
  if( number > number3) { // swap number with number3
    temp = number3;
    number3 = number;
    number = temp;
  }
  if( number > number2) { //swap number with number2
    temp = number2;
    number2 = number;
    number = temp;
  }
  if( number > number1) {
    number1 = number;
  }
}
console.log(number1)
console.log(number2)
console.log(number3)
```

If the three highest but not necessarily different values need to be found, change the `>` tests to `>=` versions.

Answer (score 0):

you have set array[i] = number1, so it will stay as 0. If you set number1 = array[i] it will set as 2

Answer (score 0):

1) Your

```
else if (array[i] > number1) {
     array[i] = number1;
}
```

never is called. If you try to debug step by step, you will see the condition is not met.

2) you have your code inverted.

```
array[i] = number1;
```

Answer (score 0):

`number1` value will be `1` only if `array = [3, 2, 1]` and ***not*** `array = [3, 1, 2]`.

Note that if `array = [3, 1, 2]`, the value of `number2` is `1` in second iteration of the `for` loop and 3 in third iteration. So the `number3` value never changes as the control never goes to the 3rd if statement.

**`for` loop breakdown with `array = [3, 1, 2]`**

***Iteration 1:***
number1 = 3
number2 = 0
number3 = 0

***Iteration 2:***
number1 = 3
number2 = 1
number3 = 0

***Iteration 3:***
number1 = 3
number2 = 2
number3 = 0

**FYI:**

```js
var array = [3, 2, 1];  // old value: [3, 1, 2]
var array2 = []
var number1 = 0;
var number2 = 0;
var number3 = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (array[i] > number3) {
    number3 = array[i]; // gets value 3

  } else if (array[i] > number2) {
    number2 = array[i]; // gets value 1 if array = [3, 1, 2] and later value 2
  } else if (array[i] > number1) { // condition never satisfied if array = [3, 1, 2]
    number1 = array[i];
  }
}

console.log(number1)
console.log(number2)
console.log(number3)
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop doesn't work because a loop repeat everything inside the loop the number2 just got overitten.

Just do:

```js
var array = [3,1,2]
var array2 = array.sort();
```